# An excluded 'ghost' page is crashing my permalink

Tags: permalinks, page-attributes

I am a SEO intern, and I'm having a problem with a wordpress page that I have to optimize.

So, I would like to make a better site structure, but when I am going to configure the permalink of the ascending page in the page attribute, the site crash.

Here is the video of the crash https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lbth0xFeh_GIqDyjpWP0FfU3tV6_WT7v/view

And the ascending page that appears "/Wolf/" doesn't exist in any of the trash or drafts of the wordpress blog

Thanks, this is my first question

Comment: Is there an image for this slug?

Comment: Yes, https://imgur.com/a/3gdx9gO
First image: On the left is the real ascending page with the slug "/produtos/" and on the right is the page that I showed on the video with the slug "/Wolf" that I would like to change to "/produtos/"
Second image: The actual page slug "/Wolf/" displaying the 404 error

Comment: I think you'll have to try and debug the mechanism that's adding the breadcrumbs to work out where it's getting that item from. Is this the Yoast SEO plugin breadcrumbs?